# Why wont the colours change using UV maps?

Tags: uv, vertices, edges, faces, uv-image-editor

[image]
Im trying to change the colour of this dress in the UV map, but whenever I try to change the image, These pieces just stay the same.

For context, I seperated one side and mirrored it so I could save time modifying the other side of the dress. I then joined it back to the dress and merged the vertices.

When I tried seperating them again to change their UV maps, it still wouldnt budge.
Im pretty much a noob at blender so it could be the simplest thing ever

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is just from the screenshot. How many materials does the dress have? *Material.005* is white So where does this teal-colored image come from? Another material? Is there only 1 UV map? Can you share the file?